# Tomcat request time out

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, tomcat, extjs

0ne of my GET requests is taking 5 min to execute in server,
By this time my UI gives me request time out, how can I override this.

PS: I am using tomcat + Ext.js.
I will make this action asynchronous later, this is an immediate request.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I changed connection timeout in server.xml, but that doesn seem to be helping.

Comment: Apologies I can't tell you how to override the timeout (no immediate help), and i'm making a few assumptions about what you are doing; but would like to suggest that you do unit testing on the resource you are GETing. avoid testing via tomcat until you have made that action asynchronous.  look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html    Good luck

Comment: Now this is occurring almost after 5 min, any idea why this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Ajax request to retrieve the data?  If so, you can override the default 30 sec timeout period. `Ext.Ajax.timeout = yourValueHere;` More information regarding this available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-property-timeout).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I have done this too. It didn help me. 
Thanks though.

Comment: @user35690 are you using JsonP by chance? If so, there is a different property to override.

Comment: what browser are you using? If you are using IE might wanna be aware of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804266/extjs-ajax-request-timeout-has-no-affect-with-internet-explorer I've put the way I do it in an answer.

Comment: THank god they have fixed the issue in IE 5.X and above :)

Answer (score 1):

**It's not your server the one timing out it's your AjaxRequest (default to 3 minutes depending on the browser). 
Override the timeout configuration of your request:**

Per request (so you can configure only those requests that you think they are gonna take more time):

If your request is from a store:

```
Ext.define("RCV2.store.ReporteConcentradoStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "RCV2.model.RegistroReporteConcentrado",
    proxy: {
        timeout: 900000,    // <<<<<----- this is the important part
        type: "ajax",
        url: "../obtenerReporteConcentradoV2Servlet",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: "registros"
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false});
```

or at the moment of calling load method:

```
store.load({
    timeout:900000,   // <<<<<----- this is the important part
    params: {
    "desde":desde,
    "hasta": hasta
    }
```

If you are doing an independent AjaxRequest:

```
Ext.Ajax.request(
            {
                url: '../someServletOrWhatever',
                method: 'POST',
                timeout: 30000      // <<<<<----- this is the important part
            }
```